# ros using andriod phones

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i'm new at ros where i have been doing beginners tutorial on fuerte. I'm planning to run ros with my andriod phone. I've seen some videos where people have used ros in their andriod phone. Please guide me where to start off with.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71200/ros-using-andriod-phones/) by [appsdownload](https://answers.ros.org/users/5596/appsdownload/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For android you'll want to use rosjava.  [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava) is a good place to start to begin to understand how things work. rosjava is not as popular so doesn't have as complete tutorials.  You'll probably want to do more exploration by reading released examples.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0